# Page transition slide effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider

I have a web site and I want to add a sliding effect when changing a page. So for example when I am in index.php and click the button ENTER I want the page enter.php to open as a layer above index.php with a transparency. I want also the page enter.php to open as a slider for the left side and not as a pop up.

I found this pluggin http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ which has a Slide transition but it is basically for images and I don't know if I can add a whole php page as content. 
Does anyone know a good jQuery plugin or an idea that could help me?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: the "problem" with this is that you need an ajax call for every page you want to "slide".

Comment: I need to do this effect only for one page, so it is ok to use ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

If you knew jQuery you could build it up for yourself easily, with jQuery Ajax methods, and a simply fadeeffect. The same for the left part of your page, but with slideUp/slideDown effect.
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well I know a bit of jQuery. So could you help me a bit more. As I understood you suggest to connect the button with an Ajax call of the enter.php and with q fadeeffect make the page visible? Is this right? Could you give me more information on how can I do something like this?